# PHP / MYSQL - Counting How Many Consecutive Previous Weeks Results Have Same Value As Current Week (Music Charts)

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, count, subquery

I'm trying (and failing) miserably to come up with a mysql query to calculate how many times a song has previously been in the same chart position on previous consecutive weeks.  So for example, given the data set below, how would I write a query (based on supplying a date) which returns:

- song name
- date
- chart position
- number of previous weeks it has been at the same position (extra brownie points if answer is 0 that it says if it's risen or dropped in the  chart)

| id | song_name | date | chart_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dancing Queen | 2020-01-19 | 1 |
| 2 | Wannabe | 2020-01-19 | 2 |
| 3 | Dancing Queen | 2020-01-12 | 1 |
| 4 | Shape Of You | 2020-01-12 | 2 |
| 5 | Blinding Light | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| 6 | Wannabe | 2020-01-05 | 2 |
| 7 | Blinding Light | 2019-12-29 | 1 |
| 8 | Shape Of You | 2019-12-29 | 2 |
| 9 | Blinding Light | 2019-12-22 | 1 |
| 10 | Wannabe | 2019-12-22 | 2 |

So given a simple select:

`SELECT song_name, date, chart_position FROM table WHERE date = '2019-12-29' ORDER BY chart_position ASC`

We should get the following result:

| song_name | date | chart_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blinding Light | 2019-12-29 | 1 |
| Shape Of You | 2019-12-29 | 2 |

However what is need to add the extra info to make it:

| song_name | date | chart_position | weeks_in_position | movement (optional - same / new / up / down) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blinding Light | 2019-12-29 | 1 | 2 | same |
| Shape Of You | 2019-12-29 | 2 | 1 | new |

Any help greatly appreciated as I've spent the past 6 hours trying to work things out myself with a lot of searches online and not been able to work it out!  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely some optimisations can still be done, but the following will give you all the output you've requested. The first part (the CTE) basically exists to calculate how many consecutive weeks a song was at the song position. The second part serves to calculate the position in comparison to the previous week by performing a join to the table to the previous week.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, song_name, 1 as weeks_in_position, chart_position, dt
  FROM charts WHERE dt='2019-12-29' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT charts.id, charts.song_name, cte.weeks_in_position+1, charts.chart_position, charts.dt
  FROM cte 
  INNER JOIN charts ON charts.song_name = cte.song_name
  AND charts.chart_position = cte.chart_position
  AND cte.id <> charts.id
  AND DATEDIFF(cte.dt, charts.dt) <= 7
  AND DATEDIFF(cte.dt, charts.dt) > 0
)

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT cte.song_name, cte.dt, 
    MAX(cte.weeks_in_position) OVER(PARTITION BY song_name) weeks_in_position,
    CASE 
        WHEN charts.dt IS NULL THEN 'new'
        WHEN cte.chart_position > charts.chart_position THEN 'up'
        WHEN cte.chart_position < charts.chart_position THEN 'down'    
        ELSE 'same'
    END AS movement
    FROM cte 
    LEFT JOIN charts 
    ON cte.song_name = charts.song_name
    AND DATE_ADD(charts.dt, INTERVAL 7 DAY)=cte.dt
) AS DATA
WHERE dt='2019-12-29'
```

You can check the results in this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iu752yyMdvk7UtxiPhzhj6/1).

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly with a few tweaks (to join further tables).  I really appreciate your help @vixducis

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column to your table for an easy querying, like previous_chart_position type integer (easy comparison for same / new / up / down) and chart_position_updatedat datetime to calculate difference in time for weeks_in_position.

Comment: The point of a relational database is not to have any redundant data. And although there already is redundant data in OP's data model (it would be better to move songs to a separate table), adding more redundancy isn't a good solution when you can the required data with a query.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @vixducis - my data actually is split between 2 tables (with the song name and info in one and this chart data in another linked with an id in place of the name).  However for ease of understanding in this post I just combined the information (and planned to modify the answer slightly myself as needed). :)